# What is a good upper bound $n^n(n-1)^{n-1}\ldots2^21^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, inequality, products

Given an integer $n \ge 1$, I'd like to have a not-very-loose upper bound for the integer $$u(n) := \Pi_{k=1}^n k^k =  n^n(n-1)^{(n-1)}\ldots2^21^1.$$

It's easy see that, $u(n) \le n^{n(n+1)/2}$, but this is not very interesting.

## Update

We have $u(n) \le e^{\left(\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)\log\left(\frac{2n + 1}{3}\right)\right)}$, and we can't really do much better!

Indeed, using [Euler-Maclaurin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formule_d%27Euler-Maclaurin), we have

$ \log(u(n)) = \int_2^nx\log x dx = \frac{1}{4}n^2(2\log(n) - 1) - 2\log(2) + \frac{1}{4} + \text{error terms}$, which is comparable to the bound $\log(u(n)) \le \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)\log\left(\frac{2n + 1}{3}\right)$ in the accepted answer (see below). In particular, we can conclude that accepted answer's bound is tight!

Comment: Taking logarithms may be a good start whenever you're dealing with products.

Comment: Ya, I contemplated the sequence $\sum_{k=1}^nk \log(k)$, but nothing pops-up...

Comment: Yes. Take logarithms, use Euler-MacLaurin, and exponentiate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to Euler-Maclaurin. At the moment, I was just thinking about the Abel summation formula, but your suggestion looks more appropriate.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ur proposal is awesome. Using EM, i get $\log(u(n)) \approx \frac{1}{4} (n^2(2\log(n) - 1) - 1)$ :)

Comment: it is the [EOIS A002109](http://oeis.org/A002109) and the function is known as *hyperfactorial*. Many interesting links from A002109

Comment: See also $(7)$ here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html

Comment: We can do just a tiny bit better. As Jack's link above shows we have
$$u(n) = e^{-\frac{n^2}{4} + \log(n) \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{1}{12} + \log(A)}\cdot \left[1 + \frac{1}{720n^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right]$$
where $A=1.2824\ldots$ is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571739/what-is-the-closed-form-approximation-of-the-asymptotic-growth-rate-of-the-super/1572440#1572440

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality):

Letting $A= \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n (n+1)}{2}$ and $B= \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n (n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

We have

$$
\begin{align}
\log(u(n))
&=\sum_{k=1}^n k \log(k)  \\
&= A \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{A} \log(k)  \tag{1}\\ 
&\le A \log \left(  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{A} k \right) =
A \log \left(  \frac{B}{A}  \right) \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Hence

$$\log(u(n)) \le \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \log\left(\frac{2 n+1}{3}\right) \tag{3}$$

The bound seems to be quite tight:

[image]

Update: as noted by comments and OP, the bound $(3)$ agrees with the true order of growth; this can be checked by applying the trapezoidal rule to the integral:

$$  -\frac{1}{4}=\int_{0}^{1} x \log(x) dx \approx \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n} \log\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) $$
which gives

$$ \log(u(n))  \approx\frac{ n(n+1)}{2}\left( \log n -\frac{1}{2} \right) \tag{4}$$

If one is interested in an approximation (instead of a bound), $(4)$ might be preferable.

Better asymptotics [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571739) (from comments).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I see you've used the concave function $\phi(x) := log(x)$ and positive scalars $a_k = k$ in Jensen's inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Comment: Now that's a freaky tight bound! I Indeed, it's no surprise that the bound is tight. Using Euler-Maclaurin suggested by Daniel above, I can get $\log(u(n)) \approx \frac{1}{4} (n^2(2\log(n) - 1) - 1)$ :). Thus I don't need to beg the error terms in my EM, and can just use your bound instead. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way for finding an upper bound is using the [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\log\left(k\right)=\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}\log\left(n\right)-\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor \left(\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor +1\right)}{t}dt
 $$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor 
 $ is the floor function and since $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor >t-1
 $ we get $$S<\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}\log\left(n\right)-\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{n}\left(t-1\right)dt
 $$ $$=\color{red}{\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}\log\left(n\right)-\frac{\left(n-1\right)^{2}}{4}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Don't have the reputation, or else this would be a comment.
As mentioned in a link posted by leonbloy, the hyperfactorial, which shows up in the theory of the Barne's G function, is related to $\int_0^n \log\Gamma(x) dx.$  Good bounds on this should give a better bound than that found by Jensen's inequality.  I found the expression

$$\log(u(n)) \le A(n):=\dfrac{(n+1/2)^2}{2}(\log(n+1/2)-3/2)+\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}+
\dfrac{9}{8}\log(2/3)+\dfrac{11}{16}.$$

For a comparison, let's define 'Jensen' and 'A' ratios

$$R_J(n)=\dfrac{\log(u(n))}{n(n+1)/2\log((2n+1)/3))},\quad R_A(n)=\dfrac{\log(u(n))}{A(n)} .$$

Then (approximately) $R_J(100)=0.892$ , $R_A(100)=0.999992;$ and
$R_J(10^5)=0.9915$ , $R_A(10^5)=0.99999999915$ (nine nines).

Comment: Interesting. Do include some detail on your derivation of $A(n)$ (not just an expression for it...).

Comment: Great answer! Upvoted.