# The product of combinations, and how fast it grows

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, products

What is the nature of $\prod_{k=1}^{k=n}\binom{n}{k}$ as a function of n?

How fast does it grow in comparison with $2^n$, etc?

My intuition is that:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{k=n}\binom{n}{k}$$

Grows much faster than

$$2^n$$

Simply because the summation is $2^n$. How fast does it grow in comparison, though?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571739/what-is-the-closed-form-approximation-of-the-asymptotic-growth-rate-of-the-super/1572440#1572440

Comment: Essentially because your product can be written as $\text{hyperfactorial}/\text{superfactorial}$ the asymptotic relation given by @Brian can be proved with help of the above link

Comment: Thanks @tired, I have never heard of hyperfactorial before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sequence is [OEIS A001142](http://oeis.org/A001142). The entry gives the asymptotic approximation

$$\frac{A^2e^{\frac{n^2}2+n-\frac{1}{12}}}{n^{\frac{n}2+\frac{1}2}(2\pi)^{\frac{n+1}2}}\;,$$

where $A\approx 1.282427129$ is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

If you only look at the "middle term" $\binom{2n}{n}$ for the even case and you use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), you'll find that just this term is growing in the range of $$\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{ \pi n}}$$

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand and evaluate the middle term! I always wondered how to do it.