# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{((1!)(2!)(3!).....(n!))^{1/n^2}}{n^{\alpha}}$

Tags: limits

if $\alpha ,\beta$ belong to $\mathbb{R}$, $\beta$ is not equal to zero, $n$ belong to $\mathbb{N}$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{((1!)(2!)(3!).....(n!))^{1/n^2}}{n^{\alpha}} = \beta$$ then
please help me. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks
I think this can be solved using Squeeze theorem but i m not able to apply it ....
how to apply and solve the problem
how to apply and solve the problem
i tried using different technique but fail

Comment: Take logs, then approximate the sum by an integral

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the closed form approximation of the asymptotic growth rate of the superfactorial function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571739/what-is-the-closed-form-approximation-of-the-asymptotic-growth-rate-of-the-super)

Comment: Also this product factorial is associated with the [Barnes G function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html) which is completely new to me and the limit seems to go to 0 or diverge unless n is small, but not too small:[demo](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lp6gnsuioc)

Comment: Please update this question so that we can find out this amazing limit and reopen it again!